# how convert hexo blog date and time to jalali?

Tags: momentjs, hexo, jalali-calendar

I using hexo blog system. I can't find a way to convert momentjs of hexo to jalali.  How I cant convert the date to jalali calendar date ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hexo use moment for date and time. For converting the Gregorian calendar to Jalali calendar in hexo first install [moment-jalaali](https://github.com/jalaali/moment-jalaali) with npm or yarn. In your theme directory create a folder name it **scripts** and a js file put these line of codes on your file and save it. (this is a helper)

```
'use strict';

var moment = require('moment-jalaali');

hexo.extend.helper.register('jalaali', function (date) {
  return moment(date).format('jMMMM jYYYY');
});
hexo.extend.helper.register('jalaaliyear', function (date) {
  return moment(date).format('jYYYY');
});
```

you can use any format of date and time in `.format()`.
after all if you want name of months in persian line **فروردین** easily put this line at the end of the created js file

```
moment.loadPersian()
```

How to use it? for example in posts:

```
<%- jalaali(item.date) %>
```